# Hive Table migrate to different env

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I have a Hive Table on Azure HDInsight WASB, want to migrate / copy over from Production to QA environment, looks like I can only do it via export / import.

1) Export tables from parquet to files (metadata included)
2) AzCopy from Prod Storage to QA Storage
3) Import tables

Comment: is it external table or managed?

Answer (score 0):

Azure HDInsight supports only export/import Hive metastore.

If you want to retain your Hive tables after you delete an HDInsight cluster, use a custom metastore. You can then attach the metastore to another HDInsight cluster.

**Note:** An HDInsight metastore that is created for one HDInsight cluster version cannot be shared across different HDInsight cluster versions.

References:

[How do I export a Hive metastore and import it on another cluster?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-troubleshoot-hive#how-do-i-export-a-hive-metastore-and-import-it-on-another-cluster)

[Hive metastore best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-external-metadata-stores#hive-metastore-best-practices)